# Hide options with empty values using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I used the php code to display list of countries in a select box. i used the following php code to display the selectbox with country options

```
$array = get_meta_values('post_location', 'project');

echo "<select name='post_location1' id='selection' class='chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active' style='height:30px;width:100%'>";

foreach($array  as $key => $item) {

if($item !== NULL){

echo "<option value='" . $item . "'>"  . $item . "<option>" ;

  }
}
```

This php code created the markup like:

```
<select name="post_location1" id="selection" class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="height:30px;width:100%">

<option value="Verdi">Verdi</option>

<option></option>

<option value="Brampton, on">Brampton, on</option>

<option></option>

<option value="Sagan Banquet Hall">Sagan Banquet Hall</option>

<option></option>

<option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>

<option></option>

<option value="The Manor by Peter and Paul">The Manor by Peter and Paul</option>

<option></option>

</select>
```

I want to hide or remove the empty options by using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not closing `<option>` that is why two `<option>` elements are getting added every iteration: One with correct attributes and another empty.

Correct:

```
echo "<option value='" . $item . "'>"  . $item . "<option>" ;
```

To:

```
echo "<option value='" . $item . "'>"  . $item . "</option>" ;
```

Otherwise, code looks correct.

Comment: Thanks pupil, i forgot to close option, now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check null like this:

```
if(is_null($item)){
  //code
}
```

like here [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-null.php)